# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header when getting from another server

Tags: java

I'm converting the object into **base64** encoded String and sending to other server and when I'm getting response from that server I'm going to convert that encoded string to decode and convert again my object, but in response they fire

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header exception.

The same code is working fine on my same method but not on receiving from other server.

**Here is my code**

```
//this is encoding code for request
        DemoTest test = new DemoTest();
        test.setRollNumber(10);
        test.setStdName("Nikhil");
        test.setStdClass("BE");

        String serializedObject = "";

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
            so.writeObject(test);
            so.flush();
            serializedObject = bo.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("encodiiiiing---" + e);
        }

// this is decoding code when getting response (from payment gateway server)

String serializedObject = request.getParameter("serializedObject");

try {
                byte b[] = serializedObject.getBytes();
                ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
                ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
                DemoTest test2 = (DemoTest) si.readObject();
                System.out
                        .println("decoded roll number----" + test2.getRollNumber());
                System.out.println("decoded name----" + test2.getStdName());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("decodingggg---" + e);
            }
```

Comment: what is the content-type at server side while responding back ?

Comment: Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Comment: try with this - "Content-Type", "application/x-java-serialized-object"

Comment: Response is from payment gateway server so it's not possible to change content-Type